# Creating a custom url when navigating to a custom module form

Tags: 7, forms, uri

I have created a custom module which can be visited via the address 
`http://myhost.me/my_module/form` where it will show my created form. Is there a way wherein instead of using `http://myhost.me/my_module/form` I can navigate to `http://myhost.me/mynewmoduleurl` without breaking anything? I'm currently using `Drupal 6`. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

1. You could use [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to declare a new path with the same callback (while still leaving the old one intact).
2. You could use [Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/redirect).
3. You could [create a .htaccess redirect](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/). (A `301 redirect` is the proper way to do it if you want the new one to permanently replace the old one.)
4. You could create a new [Path Alias](https://drupal.org/node/31644).

Comment: I'm quite new to Drupal, can you please show me how it's done? I edited my module function to something like this, `function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['time'] = array(
    'title' => t('My form'),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}` but when I navigate http://myhost.me/time it says page cannot be displayed.

Comment: never mind my previous comment, I already solved it using Pathauto module. Thanks man.

Comment: Your problem could have been if you didn't clear caches after changing the `hook_menu()` function.